# Seperate plugin and theme files

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, rest-api

I am in desperate need of help, regarding the following issue:

I need to establish an API Connection to Salesforce, so that a user can search and retrieve certain data out of Salesforce.
I thought, that a plugin would be the best choice, so that the functionality is not dependent on a certain theme.

Here comes my issue:
I want the search form to be added via short-code, so that it can be reused. So far so good.
Then I gave the form an action attribute to call another php file, which retrieves the entered data to search for, and list the search results.

Now when I call that second file, I get the error ***Call to undefined function get_header()***.
But I need the header of the selected theme to be displayed on that page, so that the whole website has the same look and feel.

It seems, as if I am going horribly wrong with my approach.

My file structure looks as follows:

```
    wp-content
              --themes
                 -- myTheme

              --plugins
                 --myPlugin
                      --views
                         --page-results.php
```

And this is how I add the shortcode for the form to be displayed:

```
   /**
 * RETURN THE SEARCH FORM
 * @return string
 */
function add_search_form() {



    $html = '
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-offset-3 d-flex justify-content-center text-center form-column">

    <form class="wdv_search_form w-75 mt-3" method="get" action="wp-content/plugins/myPlugin/views/page-results.php">
        <div class="mb-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="searchByLocation"
                   placeholder="City">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="searchByName"
                   placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-2">
            <select name="countryChoice" class="text-center">
                <option value="EN">England</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-transparent text-light mt-3">GO</button>
    </form>

</div>';

    echo $html;
}

add_shortcode( 'wdv_search_form', 'add_search_form' );
```

Is my approach right and what would be best-practice for my use-case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't link directly to plugin/theme PHP files to handle requests for this exact reason - the WordPress environment won't be loaded, hence your undefined function error.

Since you've implemented a shortcode-approach to integrate with the theme, you could just point the form to itself (i.e. remove the `action` attribute) and then dynamically handle the output based on if the form has been submitted, for example:

```php
function add_search_form() {
    if ( ! empty( $_GET['countryChoice'] ) ) {
        // Return search results HTML
    } else {
        // Return form HTML
    }
}
```

If you want the theme to have more control over the entire template for search results, you could override the template that *WordPress* will load like so:

```php
add_filter( 'template_include', function ( $template ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_GET['countryChoice'] ) ) {
        $template = locate_template( 'my-plugin-search-results.php' );
    }

    return $template;
});
```

This would load the *theme* template file `my-plugin-search-results.php` if there is a non-empty `countryChoice` URL parameter - you might want to add more conditions to ensure the template isn't overloaded for other WP requests.

These are just a couple of ideas - if you update your question with more context, we might be able to offer more specific help/suggestions.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. You helped me a lot, thank you for that! I went with a Class apporach which renders my templates for me now, while keeping my shortcode-apporach!